# Errno2, file not found (even though i put the file in the same folder as the script)

Tags: python, file-not-found

I am a beginner trying to make a name sniper, and I have a file i want to open. I keep on getting the file not found error even though i have put it in the same folder. this is the code:

```
    accounts = open("accounts.txt", "r")
    accounts = f.read()
```

it comes back with this error:

```
File "c:/users/(my username)/AXESNIPE/lib/AXESNIPE.py", line 73, in <module> 
accounts = open("accounts.txt","r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'accounts.txt'
```

and this is where my file is：

[image]

if anyone can help that would be really cool idk why this is happening ive spent way to long on this ok thanks bye

Comment: how are you executing the script? From which folder?

Answer (score 0):

1. what is f? you mean `accounts.read()` i guess
2. You didn't add full file path i suppose. if your file is where your script is then you may have to add full path of the file or run in inside sep env.

try this :

```
import os

file = "c:/users/(my username)/AXESNIPE/lib/accounts.txt" # your file path here.
if os.path.exists(file):
    accounts = open(file, "r")
    accounts = accounts.read()
else:
    print(f"No Files Found Matching This Name :: {file}")
```

Comment: 1. idk, i watched some tutorial and they put it before read, so i used it
2. didnt work ;-; thanks tho
(edit) wait nvm i didnt see your edit. reading it now
OMG IT WORKED TY SO MUCH